# Angular 2 (Ionic 2): intercept ajax requests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

With Angular 1.x is possible to intercept all ajax requests with some code like:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('interceptRequests');
...
var app_services = angular.module('app.services', []);
   app_services.factory('interceptRequests', [function () {
   var authInterceptorServiceFactory = {};
   var _request = function (config) {
   //do something here
   };
   var _responseError = function (rejection) {
   //do something here
   }
   authInterceptorServiceFactory.request = _request;
   authInterceptorServiceFactory.responseError = _responseError;
   return authInterceptorServiceFactory;
}]);
```

Is there anything similar (or out-of-the-box) in Angular 2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An approach could be to extend the `HTTP` object to intercept calls:

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomHttp extends Http {

  request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    console.log('request...');
    return super.request(url, options).catch(res => {
      // do something
    });        
  }

  get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    console.log('get...');
    return super.get(url, options).catch(res => {
      // do something
    });
  }
}
```

and register it as described below:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    new Provider(Http, {
      useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) => new CustomHttp(backend, defaultOptions),
      deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
  })
]);
```

You can leverage for example the `catch` operator to catch errors and handle them globally...

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/ukcJRuZ7QKlV73jiUDd1?p=preview.

Comment: This seems a good implementation. I tried but I'm having this error when use the get() method from the CustomHttp: ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: _get(...).call(...).catch is not a function

Comment: @Chris You need to import the `catch` operator like this: `import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch`

Comment: Now this piece of code worked (and removed the constructor from the CustomHttp). But now I have other error: ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'build' of undefined in the line that contains function XHRConnection(req, browserXHR, baseResponseOptions) { ... var _xhr = browserXHR.build();